# Triple bunk bed design safety and difficulty

Tags: screws, weight-capacity

[image]

[pdf link to plan](https://jenwoodhouse.com/plans/Triple-Bunk-Bed.pdf?utm_source=MadMimi&utm_medium=email&utm_content=Triple+Bunk+Bed+PLANS%21&utm_campaign=20180813_m146673541_Triple+Bunk+Bed&utm_term=++CLICK+TO+DOWNLOAD+PDF+PLANS++)

I am planning to build this triple bunk this weekend. I plan to add “cleats” (not sure if this is the correct word) in the form of 2inx4in’s between the sections, on the inner side of the support posts. The bed frame will be resting on these cleats with the bed frame and the cleats glued and screwed into the long corner posts. Does this sound like satisfactory structural support if the bed were occupied by large adults? We are trying to avoid the bed frames becoming victim to a sheer force disaster and collapsing.

Comment: The overall height is 7'4".  I hope you have at least 9' or 10' clearance to ceilings to access the top bunk.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the plans they use carriage bolts to attach the bed frame to the uprights. These are very resistant to sheer loads. The [article on the website](https://jenwoodhouse.com/triple-bunk-bed/) also shows a strength test with a full sized adult.

Your idea of adding supports is the same principle of jack studs in house framing. You can screw and glue the "scrap" 2x4s cut to 29 3/4 inches they suggest as spacers as the permanent supports.

Also if you have the tools you may whish to upgrade from pocket hole screws to dowels or mortise & tenon